# Failure installing perl module WWW::Curl, can't link libcurl

Tags: linux, perl, curl

I have been trying to install WWW::Curl on my web server, with no success. It fails with a linkage error:

> /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../lib64/libcrypto.a(x86_64cpuid.o): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against `OPENSSL_cpuid_setup' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
>   /usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>   make: *** [blib/arch/auto/WWW/Curl/Curl.so] Error 1

I've tried to track down the problem with little success - Curl and curl_devel are installed, and the installation doesn't fail on curl-config earlier in the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compile OpenSSL with `CFLAGS=-fPIC`.

Comment: It looks like this is my only option, unfortunately. The existing form has to remain for other dependencies, so I may have to have two in parallel and point curl to the right one.